# Getting the base url using $location in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a url which looks like below

```
http://localhost:8080/test#/users/list
```

When I use the below:-

```
$location.url() gives me -> "users/list"
$location.path() gives me -> "users/list"
$location.absUrl() gives me ->"http://localhost:8080/test#/users/list" the entire url
$location.host() gives me-> "localhost"
```

Is there any way I can get just :- `http://localhost:8080/test#/` or even `test#/` ?

I could get the entire url and split it on `/`, but was trying to find if there was another way.

Comment: `$location.absUrl().replace($location.path(), '')`?

Comment: That would work but when the url changes to something like :-`http://localhost:8080/test?someid=123&debug=true#/users/list` it would give me `http://localhost:8080/test?someid=123&debug=true#` rather than `http://localhost:8080/test` @HereticMonkey

Comment: That URL isn't really something you would get in a typical AngularJS application. Generally the URL before the # stays constant, since AngularJS is taking care of the routing. If you're not using AngularJS for routing, `$location` may be of less use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can use:

```
$window.location.pathname
```

With `http://localhost:8080/test#/users/list`, it returns `/test`

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Comparing `$location` to `window.location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#comparing-location-to-window-location-)
- [MDN Web API Reference - window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)
- [MDN Web API Reference - HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/pathname)